# Extracting the configuration of a Dispatcher programmatically

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, threadpool, akka-stream

I am using Play with AKKA-Streams. Is there a way to get the configuration of a certain Dispatcher through the code itself?

For example, if I get the Dispatcher so:

```
lazy val blockingDispatcher = actorSystem.dispatchers.lookup("blocking-dispatcher")
```

How would I then get the size of its throughput, or the type of executor it uses?

Comment: Why do you need that? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Well, I tried to configure the default dispatcher to use a fixed-size thread pool but I kept seeing in the log that new threads are being created (though there was no indication in the log of an error). This was the original reason for my question -- I wanted to make sure that the values in the configuration file were "registered" correctly. Since then I found the bug, and indeed my configuration was not correct.

Comment: Better edit your question to share your configuration and also what you expect from it.